# Xib, text change

Tags: swift, label, xib

Добрый вечер, как работать с Label который висит на xib?

LabelName.text = "Текст Label" ошибка связанная с "uexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Ну тогда покажите нам пожалуйста тот самый xib, который у Вас вызвал проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

При нажатии на метку на карте должен появляться xib с данными

[image: При name.text = "Текст Label" выводит ошибку Optinal value]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если не привязывать текст к label, то все работает, только привязываю - ошибка.